# Transitionning from Elastic 1.4 to 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm preparing an update of my elastic search server from 1.4 to the 2.X releases.
I have prepared the migration with the tool provided (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration/tree/1.x) and I have mapping conflicts.

**Conflicting field mappings :**
    `Mapping for field nginx_access:timestamp conflicts with: nginx_error:timestamp. Check parameters: format, norms.enabled, type`

Effectively, the formats are different :

`$ curl -XGET /_mapping/nginx_access/field/timestamp?pretty
{
        "timestamp" : {
          "full_name" : "timestamp",
          "mapping":{"timestamp":{"type":"string","norms":{"enabled":false},"fields":{"raw":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","ignore_above":256}}}}
        }
}`

`$ curl -XGET /_mapping/nginx_error/field/timestamp?pretty
{
        "timestamp" : {
          "full_name" : "timestamp",
          "mapping":{"timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd"}}
        }
}`

I understand I cannot change a mapping type, so I need to recreate the index with a new mapping. However, it's **Logstash** that creates the mapping (dynamically?) and I don't have any configuration on my side for that. Can I *duplicate* an index and just change a single mapping type on the fly before it gets indexed ? I don't really see how, in fact. It seems to me quite complicated to recreate the index (there is a lot of other document types in there with a lot of other mappings).

I would like to update my old indices once and for all - and that all the timestamps have the same type, preferably.

What's the simplest solution ? Is there a plugin that would do this automatically ? (for the 1.4 revision)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The mapping are not created by Logstash, they are created dynamically (depending on the content of the fields) by Elasticsearch when it receives the documents.
You can't update existing mappings, you'll have to create new index, and when reindexing, you'll have to make sure that the timestamps are of the same type so that their mappings are the same.

You can specify [Index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to be use when creating index, which will be used when Elasticsearch creates the index. The pattern can specify mappings which you don't want to be dynamically generated. Yours would look like this:

```
{
  "nginx": {
    "template": "nginx_*",
    "mappings": {
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.